# How to identify an unknown species from its genome sequence

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics, dna-sequencing, genomics, blast

I am currently using ILLUMINA PE DNA sequence data, which I trimmed (Trimmomatic), corrected (Rcorrector) and assembled (SPAdes). I am now interested in using the genetic sequences from my contigs to identify the original organism (I know it is a bacterium).

I have tried using ncbi's BLASTn on one of my contigs with default parameters, on nucleotide collection database. The contig length is about 360 000 bases long. I let the query run for 30 minutes before stopping, nothing came of it. I am assuming 360 kbp is too long.

I was thinking of maybe using a ribosomal subunit sequence (which are used in phylogenetics) to identify the species, or at the very least find the taxonomic family. Is this approach feasible? How can I identify ribosonal subunit sequence from my total sequence?

If not, what would be the best way to approach this question?

Comment: Did you use web interface BLASTn or local instalation? What was the library against which you run your query? How long was the contig? 30 minutes seems long.

Comment: Crossposted here https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/14487/how-to-identify-an-unknow-species-from-a-fasta-containing-genetic-sequences

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been crossposted to another (more appropriate) SE site. It also seems to fit this sites criteria for ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).

Comment: @tyersome Definitely Not homework. This is my first time using a StackExchange platform (other than StackOverflow), did not know of the "no cross-posting" rule. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: One of the reasons for the "no-cross posting" rule is that members of one list may spend time and effort answering a question unaware that the question has already been answered on another list.

Comment: So how did you solve it? Blasting pieces of your contigs should give good guesses and https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi should work fine with a 360kb contig (restrict to bacteria).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a tool designed for this purpose such as [GTDB-tk](https://github.com/Ecogenomics/GTDBTk) (slow but informative), [mash](https://mash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) (very fast but very reference-dependent), or something similar.